# Select SUM by each year in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

Expense table

```
id           expense      expense_date                     product_id

1              10           2012-01-03                       1

2              10           2014-02-01                       2

3              10           2014-02-03                       1

4              10           2012-07-03                       1
```

Product table

```
product_id                product_name             purchase_date

 1                            car                    2010-02-01

 2                           bike                    2014-03-01
```

I would like to achieve the result to something like this by summing the expenses grouping by product_id where the the expense_date is between the purchase_date to it's next year:

```
Year        Expense         Product_name      

 1             0                 car                 2010-02-01 to 2011-02-01

 2            10                 car                 2011-02-01 to 2012-02-01

 3            10                 car                 2012-02-01 to 2013-02-01

 4             0                 car                 2013-02-01 to 2014-02-01

 5            10                 car                 2014-02-01 to 2015-02-01               

 1            10                 bike                2014-03-01 to 2015-03-01
```

Comment: How do the year ranges get created?  Are you supplying each of those?  If so, why wouldn't `2014-03-01` be included for `car`?

Comment: Year range is actually calculated based on the purchased date and I don't know how to get this year range. For example, car was purchased on 2010-02-01 so by 2011-02-01, it is one year. The calculation will continue until the current year+1.

Comment: How do you establish the first record for a given group and why is the first row empty?  What if the purchased date is `2010-03-01` -- should that return a different grouping, which could result in a group per month?  Please update your question with your grouping logic.

Comment: By first row empty, you mean 0 in the first row right? It's zero because there were no expenses between 2010-02-01 to 2011-02-01. Please check the expense table. The expenses are grouped by product_id where the expense_date is between purchase_date and Year(purchase_date)+1. This needs to be recursive till current_year+1(2015). Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Create a view which handles joins, brining required table(s) into one chunk & perform a grouping query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwMaxExpenseDate
AS 
    SELECT product_id, MAX(expense_date) AS 'max_expense_date'
    FROM Expense
    GROUP BY product_id

DECLARE @PossibleYearRange TABLE
(
    product_id INT,
    YearStart DATETIME,
    YearEnd DATETIME
);

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT p.product_id, max_expense_date, purchase_date, 1 As Number
    FROM Product p
    LEFT JOIN vwMaxExpenseDate e
    ON p.product_id = e.product_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT product_id, max_expense_date, purchase_date, Number + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Number <= (YEAR(max_expense_date) - YEAR(purchase_date)) 
)
INSERT INTO @PossibleYearRange
(
    product_id,
    YearStart,
    YearEnd
)
SELECT product_id, 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR(purchase_date) + Number - 1) + '-' 
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MONTH(purchase_date)) + '-' 
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DAY(purchase_date))) AS 'YearStart',
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR(purchase_date) + Number) + '-' 
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MONTH(purchase_date)) + '-' 
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DAY(purchase_date))) AS 'YearEnd'
FROM CTE
ORDER BY product_id ASC, NUMBER ASC

SELECT MAX(p.product_id) AS product_id, MAX(product_name) AS product_name, YearStart, YearEnd, COALESCE(SUM(expense), 0) AS TotalExpensePerYear
FROM @PossibleYearRange p
LEFT JOIN Expense e
ON p.product_id = e.product_id AND
expense_date BETWEEN YearStart AND YearEnd
INNER JOIN Product d 
ON p.product_id = d.product_id
GROUP BY YearStart, YearEnd
ORDER BY MAX(p.product_id) ASC
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer a while ago. This is to include expense 0 which is not declared in the Expense table for the respective year range. Thanks!

Comment: This is looking very good. Thanks. I am testing it now. Will get back soon.

Comment: Hatjhie, your solution works. On a side note question. Is there any performance benefit in using view?

Comment: No. There is no performance benefit in using view unless it's an indexed view which is not applied in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @BeginsAt as datetime
declare @numOf as int

set @BeginsAt = (select min(purchase_date) from Products)
set @BeginsAt  = dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,@BeginsAt),0) -- force to 1st of Year

set @numOf = (year(getdate()) - year(@BeginsAt))+1

;with YearRange (id, StartAt, StopAt)
as (
    select 1 as id, @BeginsAt, dateadd(Year,1,@BeginsAt)
    union all
    select (id + 1) , dateadd(Year,1,StartAt) , dateadd(Year,1,StopAt)
    from YearRange
    where (id + 1) <= @numOf
    )
select
        y.id
      , coalesce(e.expense,0)  expense
      , p.product_name
      , y.startAt
      , dateadd(day,-1,y.StopAt)
from YearRange Y
left join Products P on Y.StopAt between P.purchase_date AND (select max(StopAt) from YearRange)
left join Expenses E on E.expense_date >= Y.StartAt and E.expense_date < Y.StopAt
                     and E.product_id = P.product_id
```

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f6b9/4)</kbd>

Comment: sorry, this was too late, but as I did it I've posted it